# three tables join is not giving desired output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have three tables:

1: Station_Details (master data table)
2: RF_Details
3: WL_Details

As mention in below image.
I need a to take data from all three table in to a output table 
Master data from Station_details and other data from RF and WL tables.
If RF_Details and WL_Details tables are having same station id and same DateTime then in output table both rows details will show in one row.
If DateTime are different then it will appear in different rows.

I tried this sql query but I am not getting the same output like OUTPUT Table.

```
  select rf.StationID, st.stationname, st.state,rf.rf,rf.cum-rf,wl.wl,DataTime 
     from  [RF_Details] rf
     join [WL_Details] wl
    join Station_Details st
    on rf.StationID = wl.StationId and
       rf.DataRecieved=wl.DataRecieved and
       st.stationid =rf.stationid and
       st.stationid = wl.stationid;
```

But it didn't give the right number of rows and output.
Please help me for the same.

[image]

Comment: Your query doesn't match the sample data (DataReceived in the query isn't in the data). Also, what is the issue with the output?

Comment: If the location of the `ON` condition matters, then you should be getting the result from a `CROSS JOIN` of `RF_Details` and `WL_Details`, which you do not seem to have.

Comment: Jeff Siver is correct. The output doesn't match the sample data

Comment: @JeffSiver I just edit the query

Comment: @vim, the query still does not match the sample data. There are column typo's in the select and the on conditions references columns that do not exist. Also, why is the output not what you expect?

Comment: @JeffSiver I think now query select columns are matching with output and input tables.

Comment: Just for reference - whilst I'm sure some people need to brush up on their typing/transcribing skills, posting sample data as *images* is not very helpful for your would-be answerers. It would be far better to post them as (textual) code that creates a set of table variables and `INSERT` statement(s) that populate them. That way people can immediately copy&paste them into SSMS, and start playing with the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always put the join conditions along with the join itself. Also, adding the `INNER` is a practice I follow to ensure no extra records are returned.

```
SELECT rf.StationID, st.stationname, st.state, wl.DataRecieved, wl.waterlevel1,
    rf.dailyrainfall, rf.cumrainfall
FROM  [RF_Details] rf
INNER JOIN [WL_Details] wl
ON rf.StationID = wl.StationId AND
   rf.DataRecieved=wl.DataRecieved
INNER JOIN Station_Details st
ON st.stationid =rf.stationid AND
   st.stationid = wl.stationid;
```

Comment: RF table has 156098 rows and WL_Deatails ahs 488266 rows but join returns 81851 rows.

Comment: The use of `inner` provides no different functionality than `join`. You should drop `inner` and just use `join`.

Comment: @vim the query will return only those records which satisfy the conditions.. Simply checking the count won't tell you if you are getting the right output. There can be certain records in you master table which doesn't have any sub-records in the other tables

Comment: Thanks @Yobik. As I said, just a practice I follow.. But good to know that I can drop it altogether

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @station_details table(id int, station_id varchar(10),station_name varchar(10),state varchar(10))
declare @rf_details table (id int, station_id varchar(10),rf int, cum_rf int, dt dateTIME)
declare @wl_details table (id int, station_id varchar(10),wl int,dt datetime)

insert into @station_details values
(1,'DEL-NDL','NDL','DEL'),
(2,'UP-LKO','LKO','UP'),
(3,'MP-BHP','BHP','MP'),
(4,'MHR-MUM','MUM','MHR')

INSERT INTO @RF_DETAILS VALUES
(1,'DEL-NDL',42,435,'2016-06-13 05:15:00'),
(2,'UP-LKO',0,501,'2016-06-13 05:15:00'),
(3,'MP-BHP',20,350,'2016-06-13 05:15:00'),
(4,'MHR-MUM',30,200,'2016-06-13 05:15:00'),
(5,'MHR-MUM',15,100,'2016-06-14 05:15:00'),
(6,'UP-LKO',50,350,'2016-06-13 05:15:00')

INSERT INTO @WL_DETAILS VALUES
(1,'DEL-NDL',25,'2016-06-13 05:15:00'),
(2,'UP-LKO',35,'2016-06-13 05:30:00'),
(3,'MP-BHP',46,'2016-06-13 05:45:00'),
(4,'MHR-MUM',20,'2016-06-13 05:15:00'),
(5,'MHR-MUM',15,'2016-06-14 05:15:00'),
(6,'UP-LKO',60,'2016-06-13 05:15:00')

;with cte as
(
SELECT  case 
        when rf.dt = wl.dt then 'Y' 
        else 'N'
        end as matched,
        rf.id as id,rf.station_id as stationid,rf.rf as rf , rf.cum_rf as cumrf , rf.dt as rfdt, 
        wl.id as wlid, wl.station_id ,wl.wl ,wl.dt as wldte, 
        rf.station_id as station,rf.dt as rfdte
FROM    @RF_DETAILS RF
JOIN      @WL_DETAILS WL ON rf.id = wl.id and RF.STATION_ID = WL.STATION_ID
)
select  row_number() over (order by s.id) newid,
        s.id,s.station_id,sd.station_name,sd.state,s.rf,s.cumrf,s.wl,
        case
        when s.srce = 'L' then s.rfdte 
        else s.wldte
        end as 'Date'
from
(
select 'L' as srce,cte.id,cte.station_id,cte.rf,cte.cumrf, cte.wl as wl, cte.rfdte,cte.wldte from cte where cte.matched = 'Y'
union
select 'L' as srce,cte.id,cte.station_id,cte.rf,cte.cumrf, null as wl, cte.rfdte,cte.wldte from cte where cte.matched = 'N'
union all
select 'R' as srce,cte.id * 10,cte.station_id,null,null, cte.wl as wl, cte.rfdte,cte.wldte from cte where cte.matched = 'N'
) s
join    @station_details sd on sd.station_id = s.station_id
order   by s.id
```

Comment: Why these temp tables and insertion.these are sample data.actual tables has 400000 rows in wl_details table and 150000 rows in rf_details table

Comment: The input tables match your sample data and assist test. I think you need to refine your question and result to state how items should be matched between rf and wl and what should happen if entries exist in rf but not wl and if items exist in wl but not rf.

Answer (score 0):

You should redesign your database: right now you have a secondary key in RF_Details and WL_Details - DateTime. Which plays a role of a foreign key between them. Which is no good and will continue confusing you every time you need to join those table or collect corresponding data.

There should be another table like `Station_Records` which will store a row per every record for that station: `(id, station_id, record_date_time)`. `RF` and `WL` rows if any should refer this table instead of referring `Station_Details` with `station_id` and one another with `datetime`.

With current structure you need to  do full join of `RF` and `WL` to get both: matching by datetime - in same row, not matching - in separate rows.

```
select sd.station_name, Station_Records.*
from Station_Details sd
inner join
(
  select
    IsNull(rf.station_id, wl.station_id) station_id,
    IsNull(rf.DataRecieved, wl.DataRecieved) DataRecieved,
    rf.rf, rf.cum-rf, wl.wl
  from [RF_Details] rf
  full join [WL_Details] wl
  on wl.station_id = rf.station_id
    and wl.DataRecieved = rf.DataRecieved
) Station_Records
on Station_Records.station_ud = sd.station_id
```

concrete implementation may consist of `OUTER APPLY` or even be without any subqueries - it does not really matter currently.

Modify your table structure and you will always know all matching records:

```
select
  sd.station_id, sd.station_name,
  sr.DataRecieved
  rf.rf, rf.cum-rf,
  wl.wl
from Station_Details sd
inner join Station_Records sr
on sr.station_id = sd.station_id
left join RF_Details rf
on rf.record_id = sr.record_id
left join WL_Details wl
on wl.record_id = sr.record_id
```